# Azure pipeline node version mismatch issue

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-pipelines, version

I am new for Azure and I am facing an issue while run my pipeline. Pipeline exit with code 3

[This is how error looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRvbo.png)

[This is configuration for node version.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUHMf.png)

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot, it shows the error: The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13.

The cause of the issue is that the latest Angular CLI version 17.0.x requests the node version 18.13.

If you don't set the angular CLI version, it will use the latest version 17.0.3 by default.

To solve this issue, you can downgrade the angular CLI version in Azure Pipeline.

Since you are using the node.js version:14.20.0, you can change to use the Angular Cli version 14.2.13

For example: **npm install -g @angular/cli@14.2.13**

```
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '14.20.0'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli@14.2.13
    npm install
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

Comment: I tried this. Pipeline succeeded but now my whole application not working.

Comment: Can you confirm what node version and angular cli version are required for your project？

Comment: If you project is requiring Angular CLI 17.0.3 , you can install the node version 18.x in your Pipeline. On the other hand, you can share the current issue with us.

Comment: @ChandikaChathuranga Is there any updates about this issue？

Comment: now pipeline issue resolved with your answer. But I am getting same error in UAT environment after deploying to it. In UAT also I used your solution. But it is failed